# Python3 ThreadingHTTPServer fails to send chunked encoded response

Tags: python, http, httpserver, chunked-encoding, chunked

I'm implementing a simple reverse proxy in Python3 and I need to send a response with `transfer-encoding chunked` mode.

I've taken my cues from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895110/how-to-handle-chunked-encoding-in-python-basehttprequesthandler) but I have some problems when sending the chunks in the format described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#chunked_encoding)

If I send chunks of **length <= 9 bytes** the message is received correctly by the client, otherwise when sending chunks of l**ength >= 10 bytes**, it seems that some of them are not received and the message remains stuck in the client waiting indefinitely

Here is an example of **non working code**:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, ThreadingHTTPServer


class ProxyHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'
 
    def do_GET(self, body=True):

        # HTTP 200 + minimal HTTP headers in response
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('transfer-encoding', 'chunked')
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.end_headers()

        # writing 5 chunks of 10 characters
        for i in range(5):
            text = str(i+1) * 10  # concatenate 10 chars
            chunk = '{0:d}\r\n'.format(len(text)) + text + '\r\n'
            self.wfile.write(chunk.encode(encoding='utf-8'))

        # writing close sequence
        close_chunk = '0\r\n\r\n'
        self.wfile.write(close_chunk.encode(encoding='utf-8'))


def main():
    try:
        server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8099)

        # I use ThreadingHTTPServer but the problem persists also with HTTPServer
        httpd = ThreadingHTTPServer(server_address, ProxyHTTPRequestHandler)
        print('http server is running')
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(" ^C entered, stopping web server...")
        httpd.socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this case, after several seconds, and only if I manually stop python execution the result in Postman is the following. Please note the missing "2222222222" chunk

[image: postman error]

But if I use this length instead:

```
    # writing the same 5 chunks of 9 characters
    for i in range(5):
        text = str(i+1) * 9  # concatenate 9 chars
        chunk = '{0:d}\r\n'.format(len(text)) + text + '\r\n'
        self.wfile.write(chunk.encode(encoding='utf-8'))

    # writing close sequence
    close_chunk = '0\r\n\r\n'
    self.wfile.write(close_chunk.encode(encoding='utf-8'))
```

The communication ends correctly (after 6ms all the 5 chunks are interpreted correctly)
[image: postman ok]

Some version informations:

```
HTTP Client: Postman 8.10 

(venv) manuel@MBP ReverseProxy % python -V
Python 3.9.2

(venv) manuel@MBP ReverseProxy % pip freeze
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.6
idna==3.2
requests==2.26.0
urllib3==1.26.7
```

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the solution (thanks to Martin Panter from bugs.python.org) in case anyone else will have the same problem in the future.

The behaviour was caused by the chunk size part, **that must be in hex format,
not decimal**.

Unfortunately from the Mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#chunked_encoding) the format was not specified and the example used only length < 10. A formal definition is found [here](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html#chunked.encoding)

In conclusion, the working version is the following (using `{0:x}` instead of `{0:d}`)

```
# writing the same 5 chunks of 9 characters
    for i in range(5):
        text = str(i+1) * 9  # concatenate 9 chars
        chunk = '{0:x}\r\n'.format(len(text)) + text + '\r\n'
        self.wfile.write(chunk.encode(encoding='utf-8'))

    # writing close sequence
    close_chunk = '0\r\n\r\n'
    self.wfile.write(close_chunk.encode(encoding='utf-8'))
```